# how to add a product in cart from external php file in magento?

Tags: php, magento, external

i've an external php file called addtocart.php who is located in my magento root folder. with this file i want to add a product to the cart. the product should have the following attributes:

sku
name
options
price(!!)
qty

EDIT:
this is a screenshot of my magento folder structure:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmli0973iflfski/Screenshot%202014-02-12%2009.44.39.png

this is my code: (only with qty and sku)

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');    
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('de');


    $image = "uploads/52f7857f039b2.jpg";
    // the ID of the product
    $product_id  = 149;

    $product     = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);



    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $params = array(
        'product' => $product_id,
        'qty' => 1,
        'options' => array(
            149 => array(
                    'quote_path' => $image,
                    'secret_key' => substr(md5(file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir() . $image)), 0, 20)),
        )
    );

    $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
    $cart->save();


    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

it does not work! can anybody tell me how to do this? Thank you! :)

Comment: BTW: it's Magento Version 1.7.0.2

Comment: @Amit Bera 
thx, but the name of my default shopview is de :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
                  $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
                  $product->load($params['product']);

                  $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                  $cart->save(); 
                  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! i've tried your snippet, there's no error but it doesnt work :( my cart is still empty. this is my code now:

http://pastebin.com/rCbvQG5M

what do you think about a session problem?